# RHEL 6 x64: running 32 bit applications

Tags: redhat, 32bit-64bit, rhel6

We develop an application which currently works in 32 bit mode only. It worked fine in RHEL 5 but failed to work in RHEL 6. The reason is RHEL 6 by default is installed with 64 bit libraries only. Moreover, we didn't find a way to choose installation of 32bit runtime environment during or after system installation.

Of course, we did find a way to install three rpm packages with 32 bit libraries required for our application to work. But it looks like unpleasant for our customers (we have to install three rpms from the DVD in the command line). So the question is:

Is there a convenient way for RHEL 6 customers to install 32 bit libraries it their RHEL 6 system? Say, any user-friendly item in menu or a special command that install the same set of 32 bit system libraries that existed in RHEL 5? What are best practicies in such cases?

Comment: which 32-bit packages do you need?  RHEL makes many 32-bit libraries available for their 64-bit systems.  For example, `yum search libstdc++` yields both an `x86_64` package and an `i686` package.

Comment: user54614 A quite delayed answer but perhaps you will like it.

Answer (score 13):

The fix in RHEL6 or in derivatives of RHEL6 is to add the parameter `multilib_policy=all` in your `/etc/yum.conf` file and that should work out.

It will enable fetching packages of all architectures and is not limited to the 64 bit versions only.

Comment: correct answers are always valued! I have removed the "is this correct" bit, since it is OK.

Answer (score 2):

I think it is just

```
yum groupinstall "Legacy Software Support"
```

That will allow people in 64bit userland to run 32bit apps

```
yum groupinstall "Legacy Software Development"
```

That will allow people in 64bit userland to compile 32bit apps

Comment: Looks like this group doesn't exist...

[root@rh6q64 ~]# rpm --import /media/RHEL_6.0\ x86_64\ Disc\ 1/RPM-GPG-KEY-redhat-release

[root@rh6q64 ~]# yum groupinstall "Legacy Software Support"
Loaded plugins: refresh-packagekit, rhnplugin
This system is not registered with RHN.
RHN support will be disabled.
Setting up Group Process
Warning: Group Legacy Software Support does not exist.
No packages in any requested group available to install or update

Comment: you can do a yum grouplist

Comment: this seems to have worked for me - fedora core 21

Answer (score 0):

If the rpms are on the dvd, then they're also in the repo, so you should be able to install them with `sudo yum install <pkgs>`.

Either include instructions in the readme, or provide them with a script + instructions... in the readme.

Comment: Make sense but we don't want to specify packages in <pkgs>. It would be better to install all 32bit userland with one command...

Answer (score 0):

RHEL makes many 32-bit libraries available for their 64-bit systems. For example, `yum search libstdc++` yields both an `x86_64` package (64 bit) and an `i686` package (32 bit). So you can use `yum`

Answer (score -1):

```
compat-libstdc++-296
compat-libstdc++-33
```

help with java 1.6 32 bit on centos 6.4 64bit