# Centos/RHEL 6: 32bit PHP package on 64bit architecture

Tags: yum, centos6, rhel6

How can I install the i686 php package on an x86_64 architecture?

Comment: Why do you want to do this?

Comment: We are dependant on having a working xdebug package. When using it in our x86_64 environment we are getting segfaults caused by "something". Same installation, but i686, works fine. Therefore, we would like to have an i686 install of php but still have the option of using x86_64 for other things.

Related bug is http://bugs.xdebug.org/view.php?id=857. Combination of x86_64, xdebug, ZF1 autoloading and PHP 5.4.

Comment: See also http://serverfault.com/a/809954/140079

Answer (score 3, accepted):

RHEL support multiarch, so you should just be able to install the i686 package with yum:

```
yum install php.i686
```

That should drag in the appropriate dependencies and everything.  You may need to add the 32-bit repositories, if they aren't already included.